# Using vectors for a phone book

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that I'm stuck on but keep on getting stuck on one part of it. The project is to Create a phone book using a vector that contains a person's name and phone number. The phone_book should be in a class and all functions should be provided as public functions. The program should provide the capability to add an entry, modify an entry, display one or all entries and delete an entry. Ensure that the phone book is sorted on the last name. Provide screen shots of entries and display of contents showing that the names have been sorted. Display an error message if an incorrect name is made for the search, modify and delete options.

Have the process be menu driven:

Add entry

Display an entry, one entry, all entries

Edit an entry
delete an entry

My problem is creating the vector. This is what I have so far.

```
class phone_book
{
public:
    vector <person> phone_book;

    string person::getName() const
    {
        return first_name[i], last_name[i];
    }
    void person::print_name() const
    {
        cout << first_name[i] << " " << last_name[i];
    }
    void erase(vector <person> &phone_book, string name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i <= phone_book.size()-1; i++)
        {
            phone_book[i] = phone_book[i+1];
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
  int numEntries;
    cout << "This program simulates a phone book." << endl
         << "You can Add, Display, and Delete one or more entries."
         << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of entries you" << endl
         << "would like to add: " << endl;
    cin >> numEntries;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numEntries; numEntries++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the First and Last Name: ";
        cin >> getName (first_name[i], last_name[i]);
    }
    int numEntries = 0;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of names to be displayed: ";
    cin >> numEntries;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numEntries; numEntries++)
    {
        cout << i << ". " print_name(first_name[i], last_name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can't name both the class and the vector member `phone_book`.

Comment: What do you intend `return first_name[i], last_name[i];` to do? Where is `person`

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: I have decided not to use vectors. My professor told me I don't have to use them; I can just use classes.